# Белый список для get-параметров nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, centos

Есть некоторое стороннее веб-приложение, в котором найдена некоторая дырка -- и хочется временно заткнуть её сделав некоторые изменения в конфиге nginx.

Что требуется. Есть ссылка на страницу вида http://site.tld/folder/subfolder/?param1=1234&param2=123&param3&core=asdf&module=system&param4=1234&param5=

Есть белый список для параметров core (штук десять) и module (ещё штук десять). Нужно написать правило / набор правил: любые значения для core и module можно пробрасывать запрос на бекенд (апач), для невалидных -- отдавать скажем `return 444`.

С какого боку подойти вообще к задаче?

PS Возможно, проще будет отфильтровать на бекенде "плохие" ссылки? Добавил в теги вопроса apache.

Answer (score 1):

Проверка параметров запроса - традиционно, задача бекенда. Но если хочется приключений то почему нет.

http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

```
map $arg_core $var_core {
    default  1;
    "one"    0;
    "two"    0;
}
map $arg_module $var_module {
    default  1;
    "one"    0;
    "two"    0;
}

...

server {
    location / {
        if ($var_code) {
            return 444;
        }
        if ($var_module) {
            return 444;
        }
        proxy_pass ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ох, ши... мапы... Ладно, концепт понятен, попробую такой вариант.

Comment: @AK собсно, я бы использовал такой подход в 3х случаях: 1) потому что мне скучно, 2) потому что у меня нет доступа к бэку, 3) хотел бы уменьшить количество запросов попадающих на бэк при вообще большом количестве запросов к бэку (за 100 per sec)

Comment: Я писал - это сторонняя софтина и мне оч-чень не хочется долго-долго ковырять её сугубо проприетарное ядро, чтобы потом не раздумывать, правильный ли я проводок перекусил. Так что добавьте 4) пришли безопасники, а патчей производителя для этой CVE нет.

Comment: @AK, тогда конфигурирование nginx оправдано. хотя бы как временное решение, хех.

Comment: лучше не вводить новый пункт, а изменить формулировку пункта 2 на "доступ к бэкенду отсутствует или осложнён" ))